# Dijit Combobox text align not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, dojo, dijit.form

I am new to using dijit and dojo. I am currently using dijit 1.6.0 and have a ComboBox defined as so:

```
this.comboBox = new dijit.form.ComboBox({
    style : "margin-left: 10px; text-align: left",
    store : this.comboBoxData,
    searchAttr : "label",
    selectOnClick : true,
    value : "All",
    onChange : dojo.hitch(this, this.onObjectiveChanged)
});
```

When the value within the combo box is changed and if the text is too large for the width of the combo box, the text appears right aligned instead of left aligned. I have read that this might be a bug in IE8 where the focus of the cursor is at the last character of the text, in which case this might not be a css issue. I am not entirely sure how to get the cursor within the combobox to focus on the first character of text.

Comment: If the value is too large to display in the combo box, how do you know it is being displayed right-aligned? On a side note, why use version 1.6.0 when they are now on version 1.8.3?

Comment: @Default I know this because I can see the end of the text rather than the begining. Like I mentioned, this is not a css alignment issue, rather the cursor being placed at the end of the text instead. As for the version, project requirements dictate so unfortunately.

Comment: Can't you just increase the width of the ComboBox??  I've had similar problems with datagrid columns in IE 8 which were solved by looping through all data, calculating it's length in PX, then setting the width to this PX value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the combo box to display the beginning of the text rather than the end by calling this.comboBox.focus() whenever a value is either changed or selected within the comboBox